# Missing Css and Js files while specifying an action in the url in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

Am working with cakePHP. And i installed and configured everything. And Am using the virtual host also. When i call the base url, i get all the css and js files loaded. but when i included the method name in the url, it shows not found. I think it is due to some url rewriting problem.
My project directory is /var/www/html/Betting/
My .htaccess (/var/www/html/Betting/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And (/var/www/html/Betting/app/.htaccess) is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And (/var/www/html/Betting/app/webroot/.htaccess) is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I call the URL http://betting.spark.com/site everything is fine. But i call http://betting.spark.com/site/index it is not loading the css and js files. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you link css file and js file? If you place css and js file as cakephp style. you can link Html and Css file like this.
js file are under webroot/js and css file are under webroot/css

```
<?= $this->Html->css(['bootstrap.css','bootstrap-theme.min.css']) ?>
<?= $this->Html->script(['jquery-2.0.3.min.js','bootstrap.js']); ?>
```